# Transition on Tooltip hover doesn't work on IE, works well in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, transition

I have checked the relevant posts about transitions not working on IE but I cannot figure out what's wrong with this one.

```css
[tooltip] {
 position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}

/* Arrow */
[tooltip]:before {
 width: 16px;
 height: 6px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 2px;
 top: calc(100% - 10px);
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #00204e;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 pointer-events: none;
}

/* Text */
[tooltip]:after {
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 11px;
 top: calc(100% - 10px);
 font-weight: normal;
 text-shadow: none;
 background: #00204e;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #fff;
 content: attr(tooltip);
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: normal;
 width: 150px;
 width: max-content;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
 line-height: normal;
 max-width: 150px;
 text-align: left;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 pointer-events: none;
 z-index: 10;
}

[tooltip]:hover {
}

[tooltip]:hover::before,
[tooltip]:hover::after {
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
 top: calc(100% + 0px);
 overflow: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<span tooltip="I am a tooltip.">Tooltip</span>
```

When you hover over the tooltip, the transition effect works perfectly fine in Google Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. I have even tried adding an empty hover CSS as I searched for the similar thing for IE but that too doesn't work. Any help on this one?

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing on / have to support?

Comment: I am testing on IE 11 and Edge..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you no need to use `calc` for this.

```css
[tooltip] {
 position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}

/* Arrow */
[tooltip]:before {
 width: 16px;
 height: 6px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 2px;
 top: 10px;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #00204e;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 pointer-events: none;
}

/* Text */
[tooltip]:after {
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 11px;
 top: 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-shadow: none;
 background: #00204e;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #fff;
 content: attr(tooltip);
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: normal;
 width: 150px;
 width: max-content;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
 line-height: normal;
 max-width: 150px;
 text-align: left;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 pointer-events: none;
 z-index: 10;
}

[tooltip]:hover {
}

[tooltip]:hover::before,
[tooltip]:hover::after {
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
 top: 20px;
 overflow: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<span tooltip="I am a tooltip.">Tooltip</span>
```

Comment: @AtharK: Glad to help you :)

Comment: @AtharK: `calc` work on IE, but you need to set specific height for `tooltip` to get value from 100% height when you use `calc: 100%`

Comment: Got it. Thanks bro for your help.